# Python Matplotlib: how to combine existing graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have built a function which I apply to different partial strings - all of this works (see steps below).

My function applied to the partial strings works, but creates a different graph for each partial string. Is there a way to combine all of these graphs?

1. Create new dataframes based on partial strings
2. Define x and y values based on columns from new dataframes
3. Train test split the data to find best degree and RMSE (find best fit out of degree 10)
4. Create polynomial functions based on best degree
5. Plot the original data and polynomial functions colour coded appropriately
6. Find point of intersection at specific x values and regression lines and label them

```
# Finding best fit and graphing it
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def graph(number):
    # Creating a new dataframe for each type of security
    df = mat[mat['Security'].str.contains(number)]
    df = df.reset_index(drop = True).sort_values('Years')
    
    # Defining x and y values
    x = df['Years']
    y = df['Rate']
    
    # Train Test Split
    rmses = []
    degrees = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    min_rmse, min_deg = 1e10, 0
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.2)
    x_train = x_train.values.reshape(-1, 1)
    x_test = x_test.values.reshape(-1, 1)
    # For degrees up to 10
    for deg in degrees:
        poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree = deg, include_bias = False)
        x_poly_train = poly_features.fit_transform(x_train)
        
        poly_reg = LinearRegression()
        poly_reg.fit(x_poly_train, y_train)
        
        x_poly_test = poly_features.fit_transform(x_test)
        poly_predict = poly_reg.predict(x_poly_test)
        poly_mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, poly_predict)
        poly_rmse = np.sqrt(poly_mse)
        rmses.append(poly_rmse)
        
        if min_rmse > poly_rmse:
            min_rmse = poly_rmse
            min_deg = deg
            
    # Creating polynomial functions based on best degree
    z = np.polyfit(x, y, min_deg)
    f = np.poly1d(z)
    
    # Setting colour gradients and colours dependent on bond type
    '''
    When adding a new type, specify a colour gradient following the format below
    Add another elif statement following the same format
    '''
    gradient_blue = get_color_gradient('#003060', '#B9D9EB', len(x))
    gradient_red = get_color_gradient('#750000', '#F5D2D2', len(x))
    gradient_green = get_color_gradient('#1A4314', '#B2D2A4', len(x))
    gradient_purple = get_color_gradient('#4B0082', '#E6E6FA', len(x))
    
    if bondtype == '1':
        gradient = gradient_blue
        line = 'Blue'
        name = 'Ontario'
    elif bondtype == '2':
        gradient = gradient_red
        line = 'Red'
        name = 'CMB'
    elif bondtype == '3':
        gradient = gradient_green
        line = 'Green'
        name = 'BCMFA'
    else:
        gradient = gradient_purple
        line = 'Purple'
        name = 'Other'

    # Plotting the data points and regression
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (18, 8))
    ax.scatter(x, y, color = gradient)
    plt.plot(x, f(x), label = name + ' degree ' + str(min_deg), color = line)
    
    # Finding the points where regression intersects with 3-, 4-, and 5-year maturity
    mat_pt = [3, 4, 5]
    mat_345 = np.interp(mat_pt, x, f(x))
    # Graphing the points
    ax.scatter(mat_pt, mat_345, color = line, marker = '*', s = 200, label = name)
    # Labelling the points
    for x, y in zip(mat_pt, mat_345):
        label = '{:.2f}'.format(y)
        plt.annotate(label,
                    (x, y),
                    textcoords = 'offset points',
                    xytext = (15, -5),
                    ha = 'left',
                    color = line)
    
    # Adding vertical lines at years of maturity = 3, 4, 5 and horizontal line at OIS = 0
    plt.axvline(x = 3, color = 'grey', linewidth = 0.5)
    plt.axvline(x = 4, color = 'grey', linewidth = 0.5)
    plt.axvline(x = 5, color = 'grey', linewidth = 0.5)
    plt.axhline(y = 0, color = 'black', linewidth = 0.5, linestyle = 'dashed')
    
    # Formatting the plot
    plt.xlabel('Years', size = 15)
    plt.ylabel('Rate', size = 15)
    plt.title('Rate: ' + today_str, size = 20)
    ax.legend(loc = 'upper left')
    
    return plt
```

When I apply the function to each substring, I get multiple graphs (one for each function), but I want one graph with all the plots combined

**my output**

```
ont = graph('ONT')
cmb = graph('CANHOU')
bcmfa = graph('BCMFA')
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**desired output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling your `graph` function three different times, you are getting three different plots:

```py
ont = graph('ONT')
cmb = graph('CANHOU')
bcmfa = graph('BCMFA')
```

instead, I would suggest you either:

1. Modify your function to accept a list of securities such that you can perform something like `final_plot = graph(['ONT', 'CANHOU', 'BCMFA'])`, or
2. Modify your function to accept a figure and axis as input, and pipe the modified version back out as output. Then you could perform something like:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
_fig, _ax = graph('ONT', fig, ax)
_fig, _ax = graph('CANHOU', _fig, _ax) # I'm just overwriting the old versions of the underscore variables here, instead of making new variables
final_plot, final_ax = graph('BCMFA', _fig, _ax)
final_plot.savefig("blah.jpeg")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer... How would I modify it to accept a list of securities?

Comment: I might do something like (1) extracting the pre-plotting logic to its own method (basically everything before `# Plotting the data points and regression`) that returns `x,y,z,f` or something like that; (2) right after your `fig, ax=` line, introduce a for loop over the list of securities where you first run the logic that gets you your variables to plot, and then `ax.scatter(...)` etc. each result on the same `ax` variable.

Comment: You are the best!! It works and I have never been so happy - really appreciate it!